# Error message "Unable to cast object of type"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have datagridview and three textbox. When grid event `SelectionChanged` is caused i get data from grid and write in properties. The problem arises when you do not click on the column has the value.

```
 private void _artistGridSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    int rowIndex = ArtistListGrid.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    int cellIndex = ArtistListGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;

    this.ID = ((DataRowView)BSource.Current).Row.Field<Int32>("ID");
    this.Name = ((DataRowView)BSource.Current).Row.Field<string>("Firstname");
    this.Lastname = ((DataRowView)BSource.Current).Row.Field<string>("Lastname");
    this.Nickname = ((DataRowView)BSource.Current).Row.Field<string>("Nickname");
}
```

How to fix this:

[image]

Text from the screenshot: *Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataRowView'.*

Comment: How about simply casting to what is suggested?

Comment: Well you should probably check whether `BSource.Current` *is* a `DataRowView` first, e.g. with the `as` operator. (I'd try to avoid all the repetition, too...)

Comment: Add validation first, check null values first, then send it to process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the `is` operator:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx

Check if it is a DataRowView:

```
if(BSource.Current is DataRowView)
{
  //...do your cast here
```

Alternatively, you may use the `as` operator:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx